# use typedef type as a function return type

Tags: c++, typedef

I tried to use a typedef type as a return type for my member function, I don't know why it is giving me this "LinkedList" is not a class error. Can someone please give me a hint?

```
template<class T>
class LinkedList {

    struct Node;
public:

    typedef Node* lstIterator;
    lstIterator insert_after(const_lstIterator position, const T& );
    // other code

private:
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node *next;
        // default constructor
        Node() = default; 
        // constructor with data
        Node(const T& data) : data(data), next(NULL) {}
    };

    lstIterator head;
};


template<typename T>
LinkedList::lstIterator LinkedList<T>::insert_after(const_lstIterator position, const T& val) { 
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
error: "LinkdedList" is not a class, namespace or scoped enumeration
}
```

Comment: Your error message says `LinedList`, but the code you've posted says `LinkedList`. It's likely that the code you've posted does not actually match the code you tried to compile. Check your code for typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
template<typename T>
typename LinkedList<T>::lstIterator 
LinkedList<T>::insert_after(const_lstIterator position, const T& val) 
{ 
    // implementation
}
```

instead, as `LinkedList` is a template class. [You need `typename`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/3093378) since `LinkedList<T>::lstIterator` is a dependent name.